# Read text file with multiple rows of fields

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I am trying to read in a large text file with a challenging formatting. Instead of one long row of many fields, the file is broken into chunks with multiple rows of fields. Additionally, the headers repeat every so often and at an inconsistent rate. Here's an example, where `fieldA` is the header label for the first field, and `1A` is the first data value for the first field. The values are mixed numeric and strings, but stay consistent for a given field.

```
fieldA  fieldB  fieldC  fieldD
 fieldE fieldF  fieldG  fieldH

1A  1B  1C  1D
1E  1F  1G  1H

2A  2B  2C  2D
2E  2F  2G  2H

fieldA  fieldB  fieldC  fieldD
 fieldE fieldF  fieldG  fieldH

3A  3B  3C  3D
3E  3F  3G  3H
```

I am trying to find a way to efficiently read in the data and organize it so that each field is a single array in a struct/cell/table/etc. The best I can think of is just to go line by line, knowing how many rows are in each block, and detect when I've encountered headers.

Comment: yep, I think your best bet is to read line by line and parse the full file according to your criteria ... then immediately write a new file with a better structure (or simply organise your structure and save a `mat` file), to not have to parse this file again.

Comment: Unless your file is very large, reading a whole file at once into memory is probably best option to start. Something like `fid = fopen(filename);s = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');`. Sure individual calls to textscan matching the format for each block might be possible, but it's a lot of work and probably slower.